# Adding a Timeout to listening to the same command for a message sent with Discord.js bot

Tags: discord.js

Hi I'd like to have my bot ignore the same commands sent for a certain amount of time for certain commands or messages, how could i apply or accomplish this to my current command below? thank you

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("usa")) {
  message.channel.send("USA");
}
```

Comment: So you want a cooldown system? That users can only use a command once every 3 seconds for example?

Comment: Correct! but only for certain commands

Comment: We need to know how you execute commands etc. otherwise we can‘t help you

Comment: @GillesHeinesch sorry for the late reply - i do not use a command prefix for this bot if that is what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
const cooldown = new Set(); //put this outside of your event for catching messages (on top of code)
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("usa")) {
  if (cooldown.has(message.author.id)) //if author's id is in the variable (i.e: they are in cooldown)
    return message.channel.send("You have a cooldown on this command!"); //return a message saying they can't do this command
  cooldown.add(message.author.id); //if they are not in the cooldown, you need to add them to it so next time, they will be in cooldown
  setTimeout(() => { cooldown.delete(message.author.id); }, 5000); //it will create a timeout and add them to our cooldown list, and after 5000ms (5 seconds), it will remove them from it
  message.channel.send("USA"); //command stuff below
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/examples/miscellaneous-examples.md#command-cooldown)

The code will create a new list called `cooldown` where it will check if the user id is in the list. If not, it will add the id to the list, and after a specified time (5000ms = 5 seconds), will remove their id from the list, and when they try and do the command again without waiting 5 seconds, it will send a failure message saying you cannot do this command.